# How to go about integrating Foundation framework (for front-end) into Yii framework (for back-end)

Tags: yii, zurb-foundation

I want to integrate the **Foundation (5)** front-end framework with the **Yii (1.1)** PHP framework for developing a web application.

Since i am new to both of them and learning to use it as i move along with the development, I am unaware as to how will i be able to use both of them for the same project.

Logically speaking i understand that the Foundation 5 directory has to put into the Yii project directory structure. But i am not sure as to which directory to use in Yii project for that.

I tried researching on the web, but since i am new i am not able to understand which is the right way to go about achieving what i intent to.

Step by step instructions to do it would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to realize that Foundation is just a collection of html, css and javascript. So you use it like every other html, css javascript in Yii.

Then if you are learning do not create something yourself for now. Use something that somebody else has done: http://bootstrap3.pascal-brewing.de/ Here are instructions for using twitter bootstrap (another kind of Foundation) in Yii. With examples and everything. Start using it, be happy that you manage to do stuff right away... study the code when you get stuck, understand what happens in there.

Comment: I have researched a bit on **Bootstrap**. For that matter, I chose to use **Foundation** after quite a bit of research and comparison between it and **Bootstrap**.
I have also seen that there is quite a few resource material that is available that assists in integrating **Bootstrap** with **Yii**. Also an extension for it is available in **Yii**.
But then very little is available that helps with **Foundation** integration with **Yii**.

Comment: go with Twitter Boostrap for now, there are a lot of themes on themeforest that use it already you can easily integrate those with your application. Then you will have the satisfaction to actually create something instead of trying to learn a long time to do something for the first time. Because you know none of them it should be the same for you anyway. In time you will learn how to do what you want but why jump directly in the deep pool?

Answer (score 0):

http://yiifoundation.2amigos.us/
They have done a good work in packaging it as an extension for yii.